# Creating a reactive Shiny app in a markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

Based on this [article](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html) I am trying to create a Rmarkdown document with Shiny functionality.

Based on the link I added the code this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("input_1", label = "Gear:",
              choices = c(0, 1))

)

renderPlot({
  output$plot_distribution <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) + geom_boxplot()
  })
})
```
````

This does show me the inputboxes but not the graphs. Any thoughts on what I should do to a) show the graph and b) make everything interactive (so make sure the plot changes based on user input

Answer (score 1):

Output `plot_distribution` defined at server side, but doesn't used at UI.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
inputPanel(
selectInput("input_1", label = "Gear:",
          choices = c(0, 1))

)

renderPlot({

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) + geom_boxplot()

})
```
````

Comment: Please note that while a code snippet _can_ be a useful answer on its own, it's preferable to leave some commentary for future readers about why this solves the problem. Thanks!